# How to add Min and Max validation in this code with alert

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add height and width calculator in my website which ask user to enter width and height size. but there should be a validation for minimum value like 200 and max value like 5000 for both height and width.

if the  use add smaller than 200 and greater than 5000 it should alert a message to correct it.

I have developed this code but its not working like to ask seperatly

```js
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    if(myBox1 >= 200 && myBox2 >=200) {
        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult = [(myBox1 * myBox2 * 0.69)/100];
        result.value = parseFloat(myResult).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        alert("Please enter Minimum Width and Height is greater than 200")
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div style="background-color:gray; border-bottom-width:2; border-color:orange;">
    <h3 class="page-header">Price Calculator </h3>
    <div class="docs-data">
        <form name="pricecalculator" id="pricecalculator" method="post" action="<?php echo $buy;?>"/>
          <div class="input-group" style="display:table-row-group; alert">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataWidth">Width</label>
            <input id="box1" type="text" onchange="calculate();"/>
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataWidth" placeholder="width"> -->
            <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataHeight">Height</label>
            <input id="box2" type="text" onchange="calculate();"/>
            <!--  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataHeight" placeholder="height"> -->
            <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataHeight">Total Price</label>
            <input id="result" type="text" readonly="readonly" onchange="calculate();"/>
            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataHeight" placeholder="height"> -->
            <span class="input-group-addon">AUD</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? It looks like it works to me, UI isn't very friendly though but that's your issue

Comment: I want to add seperate alert box. you can see in if condition both the height and width with && operation I want it sepratly gives alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    if (showAlert(myBox1, 'Width') && showAlert(myBox2, 'Height')) {
        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult = [(myBox1 * myBox2 * 0.69)/100];
        result.value = parseFloat(myResult).toFixed(2);
    }
}

function showAlert(boxValue, type) {
    if(boxValue < 200) {
        alert("Please enter Minimum " + type + " greater than 200");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The event `change` fires when input-element loses focus. 
I would use the following decision:

```
function startValidator(){
    var oldWidth = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var oldHeight = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    setInterval(function(){
        var newWidth = document.getElementById('box1').value;
        var newHeight = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        if (newWidth!=oldWidth || newHeight!=oldHeight){
             calculate();
             oldWidth = newWidth;
             oldHeight = newHeight;
        }
    },400);
}
```

Comment: what is 400 in this code. and how can a display alert box. I am new in javascript.

Comment: this code call your function calculate(). Put your function near this code.

Comment: erm... no. Why would you use an interval for validation